# FFmpeg - dropping duplicate frames

Tags: ffmpeg

FFmpeg knows about duplicate frames in the input video stream as it outputs a message like this:

> More than 1000 frames duplicated

Is there some way to tell it: "Not include duplicates into the output stream, please?"

**EDIT (ADDED):**

I tried this command (thanks to *Mulvya*):

```
ffmpeg -i scene.mkv -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -vsync 0 -map 0:v  scene.mp4
```

and obtained the target video `scene.mp4` with the same duration and (almost) identical in playback with original.

The command with full output of it is here:

```
>ffmpeg -i scene.mkv -profile:v baseline -level 3.1 -vsync 0 -map 0:v  scene.mp4
ffmpeg version N-83585-ga5c1c7a Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nv
enc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libblur
ay --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-
libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-lib
rtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amr
wbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enabl
e-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 47.100 / 55. 47.100
  libavcodec     57. 80.101 / 57. 80.101
  libavformat    57. 66.102 / 57. 66.102
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 73.100 /  6. 73.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'scene.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libmkv 0.6.5
    TITLE           : New Project
    DIRECTOR        : Big Mac
    COMPOSER        : Big Mac
    DESCRIPTION     : This video is about New Project
  Duration: 00:03:11.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1025 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709, progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30 fps, 30 tbr
, 1k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 224 kb/s
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] 264 - core 148 r2762 90a61ec - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.h
tml - options: cabac=0 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 t
rellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 i
nterlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40
 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'scene.mp4':
  Metadata:
    DESCRIPTION     : This video is about New Project
    TITLE           : New Project
    DIRECTOR        : Big Mac
    COMPOSER        : Big Mac
    encoder         : Lavf57.66.102
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30
 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.80.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 4602 fps=185 q=-1.0 Lsize=   10688kB time=00:03:11.90 bitrate= 456.3kbits/s speed= 7.7x
video:10651kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.349428%
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] frame I:24    Avg QP:20.07  size: 27706
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] frame P:4578  Avg QP:21.30  size:  2237
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] mb I  I16..4: 20.4%  0.0% 79.6%
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] mb P  I16..4:  2.0%  0.0%  2.4%  P16..4: 22.9%  4.2%  1.3%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:67.3%
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 47.9% 84.7% 30.2% inter: 4.5% 23.4% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 36% 26% 11% 26%
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 31% 23% 13%  5%  7%  8%  5%  5%  3%
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 39% 26% 27%  8%
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] ref P L0: 82.8% 10.5%  6.7%
[libx264 @ 00000000005c6c40] kb/s:454.58
```

Comment: Without any details, my guess would be to add `-vsync 0` as an output option.

Comment: @Mulvya - Thanks - by your answer it seems that I misunderstood the cited message. It probably says about duplicated time stamps and not about identical frames - which is my problem. I have many groups of identical frames and my goal is to put only 1 exemplar of successive identical frames into the output stream.

Comment: @Mulvya - To be honest I don't know if I *really* have groups of identical frames - I deducted it only from playback of the video. Your `-vsync 0` didn't help.

Comment: Need to see command and full console log.

Comment: @Mulvya - Thank for your goodwill, I added them into my question.

Comment: Don't see any frames duplicated. BTW, the message you quoted - *More than 1000 frames duplicated* - is not ffmpeg's analysis of the input. ffmpeg duplicates or drops frames when the input and output framerates differ. You need to use the [mpdecimate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37089629/5726027) filter to remove duplicates in the input.

Comment: @Mulvya Yes, it is **precisely what I need**, thank you **very, very much!** I'm glad to have opportunity upvote at least that your answer (but I'll upvote this, too, if you rewrite it as an answer).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Don't see any frames duplicated. The message you quoted - *More than 1000 frames duplicated* - is not ffmpeg's analysis of the input. FFmpeg duplicates or drops frames when the input and output framerates differ. You need to use the [mpdecimate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089629/5726027) filter to remove duplicates in the input:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB out.mp4
```

Comment: I used above command but voice and video are not sinked

Comment: Use `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -c:a copy -vsync vfr out.mp4`. The duration will be the same but the duplicate frames will be gone.

Comment: did not work
I have a bad problem with DVB mpg recorded files.
FFMPG can not edit these files.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f12Qf.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f12Qf.jpg) I've used above command then video has converted but sound and video not sink

Comment: I tried the solution here and none of them seem to work when you need to trim the video and keep the audio. I found a solution I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67322549/283411)